# Execute an insert query using C

Tags: mysql, c, insert

I want to insert into mysql database from C.
Here is my code:

...

```
for (i=0;i<nb_of_subscribers*hits_subscriber;i++)

   { RandomSub= rand() % nb_of_subscribers + 1;
   RandomContent= rand() % (contents_tag*tags) + 1;

    mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO CONTENT_HITS(CONTENT_ID,SUBSCRIBER_ID) VALUES(RandomContent,RandomSub)");}
```

...
The problem is :The insert query is not executed and nothing appears in the database.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do the values for `RandomSub` and `RandomContent` (that you've declared) actually get into the query you're executing? You're trying to run

```
INSERT INTO CONTENT_HITS(CONTENT_ID,SUBSCRIBER_ID) VALUES(RandomContent,RandomSub)
```

which will fail as it's trying to put two strings into (I guess) two integer fields.

You need to substitute the values of `RandomContent` and `RandomSub` into the string:

```
char q[1024];
for (i=0;i<nb_of_subscribers*hits_subscriber;i++)
{

    RandomSub= rand() % nb_of_subscribers + 1;
    RandomContent= rand() % (contents_tag*tags) + 1;

    sprintf(q,"INSERT INTO CONTENT_HITS(CONTENT_ID,SUBSCRIBER_ID) VALUES(%d,%d)",RandomContent,RandomSub);

    mysql_query(conn, q);
}
```

As @SpacedMonkey says - you should be using a prepared statement for this

Pretty basic C stuff to be honest.

PS - do some accepts - 10% isn't great

Comment: Just another little basic question:How to delete all rows of content_hits? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Writing the name of a variable in a string is not the same as writing its value.

One way to get the values into the query string is using sprintf() like this:

```
for ( i = 0; i < nb_of_subscribers * hits_subscriber; i++ ) {
    char query[80] = {0};

    RandomSub= rand() % nb_of_subscribers + 1;
    RandomContent= rand() % (contents_tag * tags) + 1; 
    sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO CONTENT_HITS(CONTENT_ID,SUBSCRIBER_ID) VALUES (%d,%d)", RandomContent, RandomSub);
    mysql_query(conn, query);
}
```

but you should really use a prepared statement as documented here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html

Comment: Just another little basic question:How to delete all rows of content_hits? Thank you.

Comment: If you're asking how to delete all rows from CONTENT_HITS, you really need to buy some books about learning SQL. Seriously. If you can't be bothered to do that, use Google "SQL basics"

Comment: i mean how to do it in C

Comment: It's just a standard SQL query. Therefore, work out the SQL query and then execute it via C using the skills you already have.